# LUIS unable to differentiate between husband and wife

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

Consider below two utterances -

```
 I love {chocolate} and my husband like {cars}
 I love {cars} and my wife like {chocolate}
```

I have created two entities -

```
  I love {wifeChoice} and my husband like {husbandChoice}
  I love {husbandChoice} and my wife like {wifeChoice}
```

When I try to train the model, these utterances report that `{cars}` is labeled as `{husbandsChoice}` but predicted as `{wifeChoice}`

User can enter both the phrases depending on who is interacting(husband or wife) and I wanted correct entities to be updated in the entities. However the result is assigning both the values in `{wifeChoice}`

Can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when LUIS isn't interpreting the intents and entities correctly it is because you don't have enough training data so LUIS isn't able to correctly identify the keywords and phrases.  Try adding several more variations of those phrases and LUIS will become better at identifying the entities.

Comment: Actually I have added around 50 odd variations, nothing changed :(
`I like ... and my wife likes ...`

`my choice is .. and my wife's choice is ...`
`and lot more`

Answer (score 0):

One option that you might want to consider (however I haven't tried it to be sure that it will work) is to use `Phrase lists` and add "wife" and "husband" as non-exchangeable words. To do this, go to your app in the LUIS portal, then go to Features in the menu and in the `Phrase lists feature` option, add a Phrase list (make sure to uncheck the "Is exchangeable?" option).

Again, this might do nothing... but worth trying.

Comment: I am out for couple of days, will try on returning. Thanks.